# Postman shows error 500 cuz Object in JSON is null

Tags: java, spring

So, I've got a Spring Application that saves books and authors. Author has Long id, String name. Book has **Long id, String name** and object of class **Author author**.
In JSON it has to be like

```
 {
    "name": "Rich dad",
    "authorDto": {
        "id":2
    }
    }
```

So When I try to send the GET request for bookList I've got next message of error:

```
Cannot invoke "kg.istschool.bookservice.model.entity.Author.getId()" because "author" is null
    at kg.istschool.bookservice.mappers.AuthorMapper.authorToAuthorDto(AuthorMapper.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at kg.istschool.bookservice.mappers.BookMapper.bookToBookDto(BookMapper.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
```

Here is the link for the project: https://github.com/uli2912/book-service

The Idea shows me that problem is in here

```
public AuthorDto authorToAuthorDto(Author author) {
        AuthorDto authorDto = new AuthorDto();
        authorDto.setId(author.getId());
        authorDto.setName(author.getName());

        return authorDto;
    }
```

```
@Override
    public List<BookDTO> getBooks() {
    List<Book> bookList = bookRepo.findAll();

    List<BookDTO> bookDTOList = bookList.stream()
            .map(x -> bookMapper.bookToBookDto(x))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return bookDTOList;
    }
```

```
 public BookDTO bookToBookDto(@RequestBody Book book) {
        if (Objects.isNull(book)) {
            return null;
        }

        BookDTO bookDTO = new BookDTO();


        bookDTO.setId(book.getId());
        bookDTO.setName(book.getName());
        bookDTO.setAuthorDto(authorMapper.authorToAuthorDto(book.getAuthor()));
        return bookDTO;
    }
```

So what's wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in 'Author' entity. The error trace indicates that Author is null.

```
Cannot invoke "kg.istschool.bookservice.model.entity.Author.getId()" because "author" is null
```

You obtain 'Author' from `repository`, using `findAll` of your 'Book' entity.

'Book' entity should have a FK relation with 'Author' entity.
Probably, in your 'Book' `table` in `database`, the column 'Author' is null, or the relationship is bad defined.

If you have access to `database`, I suggest you check the `table` 'Book' and find the value of related-column 'Author'. If this column can be nullable, you should control this in your code.

```
public AuthorDto authorToAuthorDto(Author author) {
if(author == null) return null;
//... your map
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this project in database you have to add auto increment in field Id of author table. check this

[image]

check your database table! is it there!
Why this much needed for ID
you can put @ID and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Not need of this code
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
generator = "author_seq"
)
@SequenceGenerator(
name = "authors_seq",
sequenceName = "author_sequence",
initialValue = 1,
allocationSize = 50
)

Comment: but it actually has in class Author, doesn't it?